# Is there a replacement for pytz.common_timezones

Tags: python, timezone, pytz

I was using the pytz module and was told I can't.

I was wondering if there was a replacement/substitution anywhere for

```
pytz.common_timezones
```

I'm using that to build a dict of time zones so that I can use the dateutil parser to convert a string into UTC, whatever time zone is in that string.

Here is an example of what I am doing

```
from pytz import utc
from dateutil import parser


def gen_tzinfos():
    for zone in pytz.common_timezones:
        try:
            tzdate = pytz.timezone(zone).localize(dt.utcnow(), is_dst=None)
        except pytz.NonExistentTimeError:
            pass
        else:
            tzinfo = gettz(zone)

            if tzinfo:
                yield tzdate.tzname(), tzinfo

TZINFOS = dict(gen_tzinfos())

# 2009-11-01 20:00:00-05:00
date_str1 = 'Sat, 11/01/09 8:37 PM PDT'
date_str2 = 'Sat, 11/01/09 8:37 PM CDT'
date_str3 = 'Sat, 11/01/09 8:37 PM EST'
date_str4 = 'Sat, 11/01/09 8:37 PM UTC'
date_str6 = '2009 April 19 2:29 PM CDT'



print date_str1, " = ", parser.parse(date_str1, tzinfos=TZINFOS)
print date_str2, " = ", parser.parse(date_str2, tzinfos=TZINFOS)
print date_str3, " = ", parser.parse(date_str3, tzinfos=TZINFOS)
print date_str4, " = ", parser.parse(date_str4, tzinfos=TZINFOS)
print date_str6, " = ", parser.parse(date_str6, tzinfos=TZINFOS)
```

Can anyone suggest an alternative way to get the dict TZINFOS ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`common_timezones`](https://github.com/newvem/pytz/blob/f137ff00112a9682bc4e4945067b3b88f158d010/pytz/__init__.py#L327) is nothing more than a list sitting in `pytz/__init__.py`.  If for whatever reason you're forbidden from using `pytz`, copy the list locally as a newline-delimited text file and read it in.  There's [no indication](https://github.com/newvem/pytz/search?q=common_timezones&unscoped_q=common_timezones) from the `pytz` source that it was generated dynamically, at least from the codebase, that is.

The strings from the list are in a format compatible with `dateutil.tz.gettz()`, which I'm guessing is what's referenced in your question.

Comment: FWIW, https://github.com/newvem/pytz/ is not the correct repository for `pytz` - it appears to be a copy of a snapshot from 2012. Going to https://pypi.org/project/pytz/, following the link to the docs  (https://pythonhosted.org/pytz/), and the docs point to https://code.launchpad.net/pytz (which is mirrored on github: https://github.com/stub42/pytz). Not very clear, I know, but that seems to be how it is

Comment: current versions of `pytz` also seem to autogenerate the `common_timezones` list, so you won't find it in the source code. The best way to get the python code for it is to do `python -c "import pytz; print(repr(pytz.common_timezones))"`

Answer (score 0):

You're assuming that all abbreviations belonging to the zones in `pytz.common_timezones` are unique and unambiguous.  They are not. For example, "CST" could belong to `America/Chicago`, `America/Havana`, or `Asia/Shanghai` - all of which have very different offsets from UTC.

Generally speaking, the task you are attempting is impossible.  It only works under narrowed conditions, when you have a predefined list of abbreviations and their interpretations.  For example, if you know you only have data with English time zone abbreviations from the USA, then you could create a dictionary mapping those abbreviations to their offsets.  Then you could pass that to the parser's `tzinfos` argument.  But you can't simply build such a dictionary from all time zones worldwide.  Doing so will lead to many conflicts.